# Meta Analysis (metafor in R): Difference between Mixed-Effects Models that have an intercept and those who don't?

Tags: r, anova, interpretation, meta-analysis, metafor

My question is more theoretical, less code related.

I am trying to enter some moderators to `rma.mv()` , my moderators are:

- 1 factor with 4 levels. Call it "F", with levels F1, F2, F3, F4.
- 3 continuous variables. Call them "C", as C1, C2, C3.

My main focus is the factor variable, I am intending to use the continuous ones as covariates (I hope this is the right way, I read I have to include them just as normal moderators in order to serve as controls).

Anyways, I noticed that the significances I get are different between a model with **intercept included**, and a model with **no intercept included**. I wonder:

Q1: why?
It should be just a constant shift in the y-direction, without affecting p-values, no?

I'm trying to discriminate the difference between intercept vs. no intercept. So help me out with the following scenarios:

Which model should I choose (among intercept vs. no intercept) and how to interpret it?

Q2) When moderators are only categorical (there are no continuous variables at all).

Q4) When moderators have categorical & continuous variables, but the continuous ones are controls (like my case above).

Comment: It's the same as regression with and without intercept. If you understand that (try it with something very simple) you'll understand the meta-analysis.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I can't make sense of it.
Especially the intercept bit, sometimes Test of Moderators insignificant though the intercept (which is a factor level) is significant. I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:models_with_or_without_intercept